# Command To Close an Open File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a .CMD file to easily copy and paste a revised file (i.e. test.pdf) overwriting the old file with the new one. The problem is that if the old file is currently open by a user on the network then I cannot paste over it or delete it. I tried using the `DEL /F "test.pdf"` command but it still doesn't force the delete. I know that there is the command `net file <ID> /close`, but `<ID>` is dynamic and will never be the same twice. Is there any way to determine the `<ID>` of the file in the script knowing the path and file name? Or is there another way to close an open file within a CMD file? Another problem is that multiple users can have the file open simultaneously...

Note: I know that closing an open file is not good practice as it can cause data loss, however this is simply a PDF file that I am replacing. Even if the old file gets corrupted, it is going to be erased anyway.

Comment: Can you schedule the file replacement at a time of night when nobody will be accessing the file?

Comment: Have a look at psfile.exe http://ss64.com/nt/psfile.html

Comment: @Kayasax I cannot seem to find a download of the PSTools.zip folder that doesn't turn out to be empty (even though the size is > 1MB)...

Comment: @foxidrive We are a 24/7 facility. There is no guranteed time when the file will be closed...

Comment: pstools homepage http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the info of the net file output on this page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490702.aspx some code like this will get the ID of the file.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (' net file ^|find /i "myfilename.pdf" ') do net file %%a /close
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a program called Unlocker v1.9.2 made by Empty Loop. [Unlcoker 1.9.2](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) There is a freeware version that has a command line utility where you call the .exe file with parameters (the path to the file) to unlock. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify this by using psfile.exe from the sysinternals suite. just modify the full path for test.pdf to point to the parent directory of test.pdf.

`psfile.exe \\(remote computer) (full path to parent directory of test.pdf) -c`

example:
`psfile.exe \\computer1 C:\pdfs\test -c`